Writing the specification to fulfill the enablement criterion when I have used an off-the-shelf module in the invention
I am writing a patent specification, and I'm a little stuck with how best to describe it.
The issue is that while experimenting with the patent subject matter (i.e. the implementation of the idea), I used a particular open-source-ish plug-and-play software as I couldn't possibly have re-created that particular bit on my own.
Now, while describing the specification, how do I convey that a little bit of experimentation may have to be done within that module (which the software took care of)? I don't want to have to explain the internal workings of the software as that is beyond my ability.
Any person skilled in the field would be able to plug in the same software and experiment to his or her heart's content, as the software comes with the required tuning "knobs and switches" built into its user interface. Moreover, my patent is not necessarily dependent on using that software. Any other implementation of the same or similar functionality would work just as well, although with the same tiny bit of experimentation required.
I believe the experimentation is not something that would be described as "undue", as it is quite a minor thing, but would be needed to get the best results.
Any tips on how to go about this would be much appreciated.

Can't you just give a generic term for what the software does? I don't know the specifics, but something like "XYZ solver" or "XYZ simulator". Then state something like: "Appropriate values for the ABC components can be obtained by utilizing an XYZ solver software".
